# Global contant flow

Tags: flow

We have a condition where we are mapping  10 answer fields from object A to a flow variable and then,lastly we are selecting a checkbox field as global constant =True. (These are all contained in a screen and it is redirected from another screen if Answer field is selected as Yes as the field is screen choice field).

So, what happens if any of the answer field is yes, then the checkbox gets selected.

Now we want to set the checkbox flag as false for one answer field if value is yes, for example out of 10 answer fields, for answer9 if response is yes then the checkbox should be false.

Can we remove this field(answer9) from the condition so that it will work or we have to create a new screen and add condition only for answer9 field and set the checkbox flag as global constant equals to false?

Answer (score 0):

First, unless this is being used for Web Services or a Managed Package, your variable should only need to be `Public`, not `Global`.

From your description, what I would suggest is to use a `public static list<boolean>ListName` so you can keep track of true/false for each of the 10 fields you're concerned about if you only want to use one screen. In that way you don't need to create separate variables, but instead can keep track of the values in the list, using as many or as few as needed.